# VB equivalent of C# interface behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In C#, it is possible to get away with this:

```
interface IImpliedReadOnly
{
    int SomeNumber { get; }
}

class Implementation : IImpliedReadOnly
{
    private int someNumber = 0;

    public int SomeNumber
    {
        get { return this.someNumber; }
        set { this.someNumber = value; }
    }
}
```

But I can't find an equivalent way to do this in VB.
If I make the property in the interface ReadOnly, the implementing class has to match those access rights and also declare the property as ReadOnly, instead of being able to implement a getter and a setter, like in C#.

Is there any way around this?
And if not, why does VB not allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use the following VB code:

```
Friend Interface IImpliedReadOnly
    ReadOnly Property SomeNumber() As Integer
End Interface

Friend Class Implementation
    Implements IImpliedReadOnly

    Private someNumber_Renamed As Integer = 0
    Private ReadOnly Property IImpliedReadOnly_SomeNumber() As Integer Implements IImpliedReadOnly.SomeNumber
        Get
            Return SomeNumber
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property SomeNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return someNumber_Renamed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            someNumber_Renamed=value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code works in C# because C# supports implicit interface implementation, **VB.NET only supports explicit interface implementation.**

If you implement the following adaptation of your C# example using explicit interface implementation, you will get following error:

Code:

```
interface IImpliedReadOnly
{
    int SomeNumber { get; }
}
class Implementation : IImpliedReadOnly
{
    private int someNumber = 0;
    int IImpliedReadOnly.SomeNumber
    {
        get { return someNumber; }
        set { someNumber = value; }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error 1   'Test.IImpliedReadOnly.SomeNumber.set' adds an accessor not
>   found in interface member 'Test.IImpliedReadOnly.SomeNumber'

Comment: @Pharap yes it's not your code. I want to show you that C# and VB.NET behave in the same way if you use explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

now try this...

```
Interface IImpliedReadOnly
ReadOnly Property SomeNumber() As Integer
End Interface
Class Implementation
Implements IImpliedReadOnly
Private m_someNumber As Integer = 0
Public Property SomeNumber() As Integer Implements IImpliedReadOnly.SomeNumber
    Get
        Return m_someNumber
    End Get
    Set
        m_someNumber = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: put Return 1 instead of Return m_someNumber

Comment: @Rony: all you've done is demonstrate the problem that Pharap was asking about.